# Send big file (2GB+) to anonfiles using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I had a script to send a file to anonfiles.com for sharing using `requests`. It emulates the suggested `curl` command:

```
curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload
```

```py
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    req = requests.post(
        'https://api.anonfiles.com/upload',
        files={'file': file},
    )
    res = json.loads(req.text)
```

This worked properly for files smaller than 2GB, but when the file grew bigger, it started printing a error message about the filesize.

I tried to using `requests-toolbelt` to send the file with no success.

```py
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    encoder = MultipartEncoder({'file': file})
    req = requests.post(
        'https://api.anonfiles.com/upload',
        data=encoder,
        headers={'Content-Type': encoder.content_type}
    )
    res = json.loads(req.text)
```

Which returns a the following error from anonfiles.com:

```json
{
    "status": false,
    "error": {
        "message": "No file chosen.",
        "type": "ERROR_FILE_NOT_PROVIDED",
        "code": 10
    }
}
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but can't figure it out right now.

P.S.: the use of `requests-toolbelt.MultipartEncoder` is not mandatory, I tried it and didn't manage to make it work. I will accept any answer even if it doesn't include this. A solution without `request` is not optimal but would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tuple seems to work:

```py
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    encoder = MultipartEncoder({'file': (filename, file)})
    req = requests.post(
        'https://api.anonfiles.com/upload',
        data=encoder,
        headers={'Content-Type': encoder.content_type}
    )
    res = json.loads(req.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**

Upon further examination, I really am not sure what's going on.  I originally thought you could fix it by sending json=json_file with the request, but then I realized you were using the encoder.  I do not know if the MultipartEncoder will work the same way with the json object.

Anyway...good luck!

I think this is a simple case of `json.load` vs `json.loads`:

`json.load` is for `files`

`json.loads` is for `strings`

In your original code you never loaded the file because you used `json.loads`, which is for strings.

Although I can't explain why it worked for smaller files so maybe I'm just off base!! you might try some sort of streaming for the larger file as well.

I haven't seen the syntax you used for the response before so I rewrote it a tiny bit to simplify it to understand it a little better, but mostly I think the issue is what I wrote above:

```
url = 'www.url.com'
headers = 'header stuff'
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    json_file = json.load(file) 
    encoder = MultipartEncoder({'file': json_file})
    response = requests.post(url, data=encoder, headers=headers).text
    # or instead of appending .text you could create 
    # data = response.text for easier use in the rest of your code.
```

Comment: The `json.loads` is used to load the response from the request, not the file. I will split it into several lines.

Comment: Ah, I see - and that’s why it worked for smaller files before! 
I was originally going off of the error message that said “file not found” / “no file chosen” - so I thought maybe it needed a file specifically. 
Good luck, hope you are able to figure it out!